# Java web application calling different other Java applications (workers)

Tags: java, spring

I am looking for a better logical solution of a situation where one core Java EE (Web) application will call/execute many *other Java applications/workers* (which can be core Java or J2EE(web) application (don't know what will be the best)) at a certain time.

Those *other Java applications/workers* will basically connect (individually) with different Data sources (can be from remote DB or REST or SOAP, etc...) and populate/update local DB at a certain period of time.

I was doing research on Java Quartz Scheduler recently. Do u have any good suggestion to me for this Enterprise level architecture?

Btw, I am using Spring 4, Java 7

Thank you as always for all good and professional ideas.

Sample diagram can be as follows:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can connect your java application with others easy with spring's `httpInvoker` or `rmiInvoker`.
More information here: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/remoting.html

Comment: Nice! Will spring's httpInvoker or rmiInvoker will re-run those workers in timely fashion (so that they individually can re-connect remote data sources and update local DB)? I will read more on this. Thank u so much.

Comment: You are welcome. Sure, you can use them to run schedulling tasks. But it you just want to run schedulling tasks, why not to use spring's schedulling? Here it is: http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/scheduling.html

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand good, but you can look at a messaging mechanism. Typically, the WebApp will send a message that will be received by all the Workers.

Have a look a [JMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_Message_Service) which it designed for this kind of use, and integrates well with both JEE (it is a part of the JEE spec) and Spring.

Comment: Thank u Alexandre! I am looking into it.

Answer (score 1):

There are basically two parts to your question:

1. How do I schedule jobs on a Java EE server?
2. How do I invoke remote services from that scheduled job?

**Job Scheduling**

The trick with job scheduling in a Java EE environment is that you are typically running jobs in a cluster, or more than one server.  Thus, only *one* of the nodes should be running that job at a time "on behalf of" the cluster, otherwise, you'll get multiple calls to those remote resources for the same thing.

There is a standard out there for this, [JSR-237](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=237), which covers Timers and WorkManagers.  Each Java EE vendor has its own implementation.  [WebLogic has one](https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/1213/wls/COMMJ/toc.htm), [WebSphere has one](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSAW57_8.5.5/com.ibm.websphere.nd.doc/asyncbns/concepts/casb_timemanager.html), and [JBoss has one](https://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/docs/Server_Configuration_Guide/4/html/Additional_Services-Scheduling_Tasks.html) (the JBoss one isn't compliant with the JSR, but it does the same thing).

If you are running one of the servers that only runs the web tier of the Java EE spec (i.e, Tomcat or Geronimo), then Quartz is a good choice.

**How to invoke remote services from timed jobs**

Echoing @Alexandre Cartapanis' answer, probably what you'll want to do is create a [JMS Topic](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnceh.html) in your Java EE server, and then when the job runs, post a message to the topic.  The remote services (whatever Java EE servers) *subscribe* to this topic, and then you can run your queries.

The big advantage here is that if you ever need to add another service that needs to populate the local DB, all you have to do is have that server subscribe to the topic - no code changes needed.  With JSch or remoting, you'll have to make a code change every time a new service comes online.  You also have to make code changes if DNS addresses or IP addresses change, etc, where as the JMS way is just configuration on the server.  There's a lot more that you can do with JMS, and the support is much better across the board.

Spring has adapters for Quartz and I think there's one out there for WorkManagers and Timers too.

Comment: Brad, Thank u. I just updated my post with a diagram. Please have a look. If u find any more suggestion will be helpful for me then please share. I went through ur reply. I am going through all those points/options right now. Again, thank u.

Comment: What you have looks fine.  I would add the code to the applications running on A, B, and C if I could.  If I couldn't change the code for those remote applications, I'd either put the consumer on the in house app server, or write the data access code directly into the job invoked by the Timer.  You could use Spring Asynchronous beans, but those use unmanaged threads which can cause problems on a full Java EE server.

Comment: Great insight Brad! I am looking forward into this approach 'write the data access code directly into the job invoked by the Timer'. Thank u again so much.

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `JSch - Java Secure Channel` to trigger remote ssh calls which can start a JVM and run the Worker class.
[Here are some examples.](http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/)